# Utilization of antd's menu component and pagination problem

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using antd's menu component. When the menu is clicked, I want the corresponding page to be exposed.

For example, I want the Home.js page to be exposed when I click 'Home Screen'.

I used antd's API, but I'm not sure because my skills are low.

```
import {HomeFilled, SignalFilled, FileFilled} from '@ant-design/icons';
import { Menu } from 'antd';
import { useState } from 'react';
import home from "./home/Home";

  function getItem(label, key, icon, children, type, style) {
    return {
      key,
      icon,
      children,
      label,
      type,
      style,
    };
  }

  const items = [
    getItem('홈 화면', 'home', <HomeFilled style={{ fontSize: '22px' }}/>),
    getItem('운영관리', 'sub1', <SignalFilled style={{ fontSize: '22px' }} />, [
      getItem('업체관리', 'subcontractor', null, null, null, {fontSize: '20px', textAlign: 'left', textIndent: "27px"}),
      getItem('작업자관리', 'worker', null, null, null, {fontSize: '20px', textAlign: 'left', textIndent: "10px"}),
      getItem('근무관리', 'info', null, null, null, {fontSize: '20px', textAlign: 'left', textIndent: "27px"}),
    ])

       <Menu
          defaultSelectedKeys={['home']}
          defaultOpenKeys={['']}
          mode="inline"
          theme= 'light'
          inlineCollapsed={false}
          items={items}
          style={{
            width: "200px",
            display: "flex",
            background: "#195AC0",
            flexDirection: "column",
            textAlign: "left",
            fontSize: "25px",
            color: "white",
            border: 'none'
          }}
        />
      </div>
      
    );
  };

export default Main2
```